# UI Router: How to pass parameters to nested views

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I've always used ngRoute for my routing needs, until I needed nested views.

I'm using ui-router for the first time, and it's been going great, except for this one thing: I need to pass a parameter to the nested views.

The idea is, a list of widgets, each has an id. I want that id available to the nested view controller.

Here's a fictional idea of what I have:

home.html

```
<li data-ng-repeat="widget in vm.widgets">
    <div ui-view="{{widget.template}}"></div>
</li>
```

app.config (part of...)

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            '': {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/home/home.html'
            },
            'blebleh@home': {
                controller: 'BleblehController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/blebleh.html'
            },
            'blablah@home': {
                controller: 'BlablahController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/blablah.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

So, let's say I have the following for vm.widgets:

```
[
    {
        widgetId: 1,
        template: 'blablah'
    },
    {
        widgetId: 2,
        template: 'blebleh'
    }
]
```

How can I pass 1 (widgetId) to BlablahController and 2 (widgetId) to BleblehController?

I tried a few things with $stateParams, but no success. Couldn't find a solution or answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Use `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant to say I tried.

Comment: Have you tried using [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have your routes set up like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        '': {
          controller: 'HomeController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        },
        'blebleh@home': {
          controller: 'BleblehController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          templateUrl: 'blebleh.html'
        },
        'blablah@home': {
          controller: 'BlablahController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          templateUrl: 'blablah.html'
        }
      }
    })
});
```

and your `home.html` like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="widget in vm.widgets">
    <div ui-view="{{ widget.template }}"></div>
</div>
```

you should be able to access the `ng-repeat`s `widget` object, and it's properties from within the child views via scope inheritance. So from within `blebleh.html` and `blablah.html` you can access the respective `widgetId`s simply using:

```
{{ widget.widgetId }}
```

This works because the scope created by each `ui-view` inherits the scope created by each loop of the `ng-repeat` (which creates a separate scope for each `widget`).

**UPDATE**

Whilst the above still stands, looking back at your question I don't think I answered it directly.

**How to pass `widgetId` to `BlablahController`/`BleblehController`**?

The answer is do the above (take advantage of scope inheritance) and sweep it off the `$scope` service and use it in your respective controllers e.g.:

```
app.controller('BleblehController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myWidgetId = $scope.widget.widgetId;
});

app.controller('BlablahController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myWidgetId = $scope.widget.widgetId;
});
```

[**Example Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/g949GtX74JuAJt0G08Xr?p=preview)